# How do I copy over artifacts from Gitlab runner?

Tags: gitlab, cypress, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to copy video of a failing test stored into gitlab's default location for artifacts.

in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker:20-dind

services:
   - name: docker:20-dind
     command: ["--tls=false"]

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  POSTGRES_DB: users_dev
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
  REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL: http://127.0.0.1
  SECRET_KEY: ""
  #RUNNING_LOCALLY: "yes"

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add --no-cache --update python3-dev py3-pip curl
  - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.3.3/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
  - chmod +x docker-compose
  - mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin

build:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - videos/
    when: on_failure
  stage: build
  script:
    - mkdir -p videos
    - sh test.sh
```

log output:

- Finished processing: /e2e/cypress/videos/register.spec.js.mp4

I'm using volumes to bind content of the container's directory to gitlab's default
directory for artifacts:

`docker run --name e2e -v "$(pwd)"/e2e/cypres/videos -w ./videos --network project-0_default project-0_e2e:latest`

The problem is I get to download only the `videos` directory.
No videos inside.

Any help ?

Comment: What executor are you using? How is your runner configured? By default, running `docker` in this job should fail unless it was setup in the runner configuration or is a shell runner.

Comment: I'm using docker executor. I'll add full gitlab-ci file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `docker run...` command is inside yours `test.sh` file and if I understand right, you are using docker inside docker. You probably have something configured like this: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#option-1-use-local-system-volume-mounts-to-start-the-runner-container

The configuration `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` is what make docker-in-docker to work. But there is a catch: All your docker commands will be executed by the host machine and not by your docker container.

So when you try to execute the command `docker run...` it is the host machine that will do it. That mean that the every path that you are try to mount will be of the host machine and not the container. The path `-v "$(pwd)"/e2e/cypres/videos` does not exist in the host machine, that is why you are getting an empty folder.

Maybe you could use multiple jobs in your pipeline to get the wanted behavior (you won't be able to rely on docker-compose to setup your services dependencies, use gitlab `services` keyword instead.)

```
services:
  - postgres:12.2-alpine

stages:
 - build
 - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
   - docker build . -t project-0_e2e:latest
   - docker push 

test:
  stage: test
  image: project-0_e2e:latest
  script:
   - npx cypress run
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/videos/**/*.mp4
      - cypress/screenshots/**/*.png
```